# Can minors with dual US/UK citizenship travel to the US on their UK passports?

Tags: usa, dual-nationality

My children have dual citizenship. We live in the UK; their US passports have expired. We are travelling to the States for a week in October. I am hoping that they can travel on their UK passports with an ESTA without problems. Would that work? I have a UK passport.

Answer (score 2):

All US citizens, even dual nationals, must enter and depart the United States on U.S. passports. [Source](http://www.usembassy.org.uk/americanservices/?p=78)

My advice would be to reapply for your childrens US passports asap. [Source](http://london.usembassy.gov/cons_new/acs/passports/renindex.html)

Comment: @Nicola Just to add to this, US embassy in London has some provisions for expedited passport renewal (for extra payment, naturally) whereby you can get a new passport within 3 days.

Comment: David, have you ever tried this?  Things may have changed very recently BUT i've never known someone to have any trouble with this.  BUT of course you are correct that dat's the law -- as quoted in the first answer here .. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30280

Comment: @JoeBlow No. I am not dual national. The first link has a line further down in the second paragraph last sentence. I am sure there are other sources that will back this up too.

Comment: An expired US passport is prima facie proof of nationality. If the airline will accept it for carriage you will win an interview with an ICE agent. He will tell you that your passport has expired and that you need to get a new one. That is the likely outcome. It's true that you could be sent to secondary examination, and there they will ask why you didn't renew your passport. The fact is, a passport is just one of the ways you can prove your US citizenship. If you are a US citizen you have an absolute right to re-enter the United States as a constitutional matter. This cannot be denied.

Comment: Of course, the airline is a private company and they may or may not accept you for carriage. But once you appear for an INS examination the calculus changes. Cases do not get referred to immigration judges due to expired US passports. The US does not refuse entry or deport those holding expired US passports. Remember that the rules are different for US residents: you do not get the protections afforded US citizens.